# Flask x Apscheduler - RuntimeError: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I am getting the following error when trying to set up a scheduled job for my flask app:

```
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

I have tried to include the function 'print_session' (which is just a dummy function to check the session data will pull through - in reality this function will query a database) with a 'current_app.appcontext() with loop as I have seen on a few other apps but no joy. Does anyone know why it is still out of the application context?

main.py

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='localhost',port=5000,threaded=True)
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from os import path
from flask_session import Session 
from flask_login import LoginManager
import redis

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
sess=Session()
login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "SECRET_KEY"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'SESSION_TYPE'
    app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = 'SESSION_REDIS'

    db.init_app(app)
    sess.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # with app.app_context():
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views,url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth,url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User,Token
    create_database(app)
    return app

def create_database(app):
    db.create_all(app=app)
    print('Created database')
```

views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint,render_template,session,redirect,request,url_for
from flask import current_app
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import datetime
from flask_login import login_required,current_user
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from . import db
from .models import Token
from functools import wraps

def print_session(value):
    with current_app.app_context():
        print('Yes',value)
        return(redirect(url_for('views.home')))

@views.route('/start_schedule')
@login_required
def start_xero_schedule():
    with app.app_context():
        sched = BackgroundScheduler()                                        
        sched.add_job(print_session,'interval',args=[session['value']],seconds=10)
        sched.start()
    return(redirect(url_for('views.xero')))
```